# add additional data to duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this code which checks how many duplicate codes there are:

```
mysql> SELECT code, count(code) as dup from tg_user group by code having dup>1 order by dup;
```

this returns:

```
+------------+-----+
| CCC002     |   5 |
| BAR003     |   6 |
| FIR001     |   6 |
| NJS001     |   6 |
| DEL004     |   6 |
| BRA009     |   7 |
| TSH011     |  11 |
| SHO005     |  19 |
+------------+-----+
432 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

the table structure is:

```
mysql> describe tg_user;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_name     | varchar(30)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email_address | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| code          | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
32 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

what will be the correct way to add the email_address for each duplicate record, so that it comes as a list, something like:

```
| SHO005     |  19 | name@domai.tld, name@domai.tld...       |
+------------+-----+-----------------------------------------+
432 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` joins the values with comma.
Add `DISTINCT` to filter out duplicates

```
SELECT code, count(code) as dup, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email_address)
from tg_user group by code having dup>1 order by dup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add email address is just add in select clause and add that field in group by clause it take minimum time.

Like :-

```
SELECT code, count(code) as dup ,email_address from tg_user
group by code,email_address having dup>1 order by dup;
```